# twig templating issue with array and index being used in another array

Tags: php, template-engine, twig

I am using the twig templating engine.

I basically have an array looping through resources which is fine however I have added another array within it which has a key, based on the loop index in the top level array

So it looks like

```
array("0" => array("a", "b",
      "1" => array("d", "e");
```

and an array which goes

```
array("0" => array("food", "drink",
      "1" => array("sport", "games");
```

If I do {{loop.index}} I get 0 and 1 from the first array which is fine

What I want to do is pass the `{{loop.index}}` into this for loop

```
{% for embedData in shareData %}
    {{embedData.embed}}
{% endfor %}
```

So I can get the array value from the second array based on the first arrays key

Is there anyway to do this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can acheive it this way, example assuming colours and teams are two arrays

**PHP**

```
$app['colours'] = array('blue', 'green', 'red');
$app['teams'] = array('leafs', 'packers', 'redwings');
```

**View**

```
 {% for colour in app.colours %}
     <li>{{loop.index}} {{ colour }} {{ app.teams[ loop.index - 1 ] }}</li>
 {% endfor %}
```

**Output**

```
1 blue Leafs
2 green packers
3 red redwings
```

Basically they can be called by dot notation and well as an array in twig, my tests didn't show a 0 index though only 1, 2, 3 using Silex twig extension to test

Comment: Can you edit and put the array you used too so I have a better idea whats happening. Thanks :)